# Crawled property is always 'Text' when crawling external static html web sites

Tags: search, crawling, crawl-external-content

I’m using SharePoint 2010 Search (Not FAST) to crawl static HTML pages on an external web site to SharePoint.

The crawled properties of the site always seem to be of type ‘Text’ no matter what I try:

So far I’ve embedded the following tags in the header of the pages:

```
<meta http-equiv=”Last-Modified” content=”Wed, 29 Jun 2011 09:00:00 GMT” />
<meta http-equiv=”If-Unmodified-Since” content=”Wed, 29 Jun 2011 09:00:00 GMT” />
<meta name=”TestDate1” content=”2011-06-29” scheme=”YYYY-MM-DD” />
<meta name=”TestDate2” content=”2011-06-29T09:00Z” />
```

I’m trying to get the crawler to recognise a data type of date.

(Please note that I’m crawling a non-SharePoint web site)

Does anyone out there know how to achieve this?

Comment: Answering to an old post here, just confirming this is an issue. ive tried everything there is to no avail. this _must_ be possible to get sorted out?

Answer (score 1):

HTML meta data is always crawled as text. If you want to have a different behaviour you must write a custom http protocol handler, which is not an easy task. The only easy way to do this is to use the date format yyyy-mm-dd so you can use a string sort.